# OOP class private/protected

Tags: php, oop

I want to display the number of the table, which I get from the HTML form, in this method: `private function getComanda();`.

I use public `function displayMethod()` to call the private `function getComanda()`.

I want the table number to be displayed in the class Table, in the `public function setMasa($nr_masa)`, which has a `switch`. It is not displaying anything at all.

When I try to display the table number with this function from `Shop` class, `public function getProperty()`, it works. I am stuck, can anyone help?

I tried to make the `function getProperty()` as both `private` and `protected` and it did not show any results, but if I change it to public it does.

This is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Preturi:</p><br/>
    Nr-Masa: <input type="text" name="nr_masa" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Trimite" name="submit_masa" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The class shop where:

```
$nr_masa=number of table; $_masa1=table1     

class Shop
{
    protected $nr_masa;
    private $_masa1;

    public function setComanda($nr_masa)
    {
        $this->_nr_masa = $nr_masa;
    }

    public function displayMethod()
    {
        $this->_masa1=$this->getComanda();
        print $this->_masa1;
    }

    private function getComanda()
    {
        return "<br /><br />Table number:" . $this -> _nr_masa . "<br />";
    }

    public function getProperty()
    {
        return $this -> _nr_masa . "<br />";
    }
}

class Table extends Shop
{
    public function setMasa($nr_masa)
    {
        switch($nr_masa) {
            case "1";
                echo "Masa Nr.1 a fost rezervata";
                echo $this -> displayMethod();
                break;
            case "2";
                echo "Masa Nr.2 a fost rezervata";
                echo $this -> displayMethod();;
                break;
            case "3";
                echo "Masa Nr.3 a fost rezervata";
                echo $this -> displayMethod();
                break;
            case "4";
                echo "Masa Nr.4 a fost rezervata";
                echo $this -> displayMethod();
                break;
            default:
                echo "Masa nu exista";
        }
    }
}



$TabelData = new Table;
$ShopData = new Shop;

if (isset($_POST['submit_masa'])) {
    $nr_masa = $_POST["nr_masa"];
    $TabelData -> setMasa($nr_masa);
    $ShopData -> setcomanda($nr_masa);
}
```

Comment: `$ShopData` and `$TabelData` are different entities and know nothing bout each other.

Comment: I tried, but I really don't get what you are asking :/ . (Method names like `getProperty` and `displayMethod` are not very helpfull, not mentioning the non english names like `masa` and `comanda`). I think you'll need to rephrase your question. What is your desired result and what are your getting? Also reduce the code to the strict minimum to reproduce your problem. The only hint I can give now is to read the manual on visibility http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2):

you are using `print` in function `displayMethod()` and then using `echo` in function `setMasa`

```
public function displayMethod()
{
    $this->_masa1=$this->getComanda();
    return $this->_masa1;              <-- replace print with return;
}
```